# How to classify these subsets of order complexity?

Tags: computational-complexity

Let:

$$f(n) = n^{2\log_2(n)}$$
$$g(n) = (n\ln(n))^2$$
$$h(n) = 3n^4$$
$$t(n) = \begin{cases}
       f(n) &\quad\text{if $n$ is a prime number}\\
       g(n) &\quad\text{otherwise} \\
     \end{cases}$$

Given that $O(g) \subset O(h)$,  I want to find the relationship between the different sets $O$ of each function:

Here are my steps:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f}{h} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{2\log_2(n)}} {3n^4} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{2\log_2(n)-4} *\frac{1}{3} = \infty \\\Rightarrow O(h) \subset O(f)$$

$$
\text{since}\; O(g)\subset O(h) \land O(h)\subset O(f) \\
\Rightarrow O(g)\subset O(f)
$$

I am confused at how to proceed to find the relationship between $O(t)$ with respect to $O(g), O(h) \text{ and } O(f)$.

My guess is so following(but I am not sure at all or don't know how to prove it formally):

$$O(g) \subseteq O(t)$$

$$O(h) \neq O(t)$$
$$O(t) \subseteq O(f)$$

The definitions as I know them are down below:

$$
f(n) \in g(n) \iff \forall n>n_0 \text{ such that } f(n) < cg(n) 
$$

$$
O(f) \subset O(g) \iff g(n) \notin O(f) \text{ and } f(n) \in O(g)
$$

Can you please help me or at least guide me? I don't know how to prove it

Thanks

Comment: Hello @zkutch , you helped me in another post. I would appreciate it a lot if you could help me with this one. I am open to receive an answer from anyone. Thanks all.

Comment: Do you know how $u(n) \in O(v(n))$ is defined an how $A\subseteq B$ is defined? Looking at some of your older questions ? I think you should state this in your problem description.

Comment: @miracle173 I added the definitions, but I don't see how I can use them in proof. Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following definitions:

$$
f(n) \in g(n) \iff \exists C\; \exists n_0\; \forall n>n_0 \text{ such that } f(n) < Cg(n) \tag 1
$$
$$A\subseteq B \iff \forall x(x \in A \implies x\in B) \tag2
$$

and the following functions:

$$f(n) = n^{2\log_2(n)}$$
$$g(n) = (n\ln(n))^2$$
$$h(n) = 3n^4$$
$$t(n) = \begin{cases}
       f(n) &\quad\text{if $n$ is a prime number}\\
       g(n) &\quad\text{otherwise} \\
     \end{cases}$$

---

We have
$$0<\ln(n)\le n,\;\forall\;n \ge 3$$
because $\ln(3)<3$ and $n$ is faster growing than $\ln$ because the first derivate is larger.

Square it to get
$$0\le (\ln n)^2\le n^2,\;\forall\;n \ge 3$$
now multiply by $n^2$ to get
$$0\le (\ln n)^2 n^2 \le n^4,\;\forall\;n \ge =3$$
So you have
$$(n\ln n)^2\le n^4 \le 1\cdot 3n^4,\;\forall\;n \ge =3$$
or
$$g(n)\le 1\cdot h(n),\;\forall\;n \ge =3$$
from this and definition $(1)$, for $n_0=3$ and $C=1$ follows
$g(n)\in O(h(n))$

But $h(n)\not\in O(g(n))$. Because if there is an appropriate $C$ and $n_9$ such that

$$h(n)=3n^4 \le C (n \ln(n))^2=g(n),\forall n\ge n_0$$

We have $(\ln(n))^2<n,\; \forall n>=3$ because the inequality holds for$3$ and right side increases faster as the left side.
So if we choose $n \gt \{C,3\}$, then

$$h(n)=3n^4 = 3n^2 n n > 3n^2 C (\ln n)^2 =3Cg(n),\; \forall n\ge \max \{C,3\}$$
which is a contradiction

---

$$f(n)= n^{2\log_2(n)}\ge n^{2\log_2(8)} = n^6, \; \forall n\ge 8$$
therefore
$$ h(n)=3n^4\le3n^6\le3f(n),\;\forall n\ge8$$
so

from definition $(1)$ , for $n_0=8$ and $C=3$ follows $h(n)\in O(f(n))$.

---

We prove now, if $a$ and $b$ are two functions then

- *if $a(n)\in O(b(n))$ then $O(a(n))\subseteq O(b(n))$*

We prove this by using definition $(2)$. So let $d(n)\in O(a(n))$ then we have to show that $d(n)\in O(b(n))$
$d(n)\in O(a(n))$, then there is a $C_1$ and an $n_{1}$, such that
$$d(n)\le C_1 a(n),\;\forall n\ge n_{1}\tag 3$$
and $a(n)\in O(b(n))$ means there is a $C_2$ and an $n_2$, such that
$$a(n)\le C_2 b(n),\;\forall n\ge n_{2}\tag 4$$

equation $(3)$ remains valid if we replace $n_1$ by $\max\{n_1,n_2\},$ because every $n$ that is greater $\max{n_1,n_2}$ is larger than $n_1$, so we get
$$d(n)\le C_1 a(n),\;\forall n\ge \max\{n_1,n_2\}\tag 5$$
In $(3)$ we can also replace $n_2$ by $\max\{n_1,n_2\}$ and if we the multily the equation by $C_1$ we get
$$C_1a(n)\le C_1C_2 b(n),\;\forall n\ge \max\{n_1,n_2\}\tag 6$$

From these two equation follows
$$d(n)\le C_1C_2b(n),\;\forall n\ge\max{n_1,n_2}$$
So $d(n) \in O(b(n))$ according to definition $(1)$ if we choose $C=C_1C_2$ and $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. So we have shown
$$\forall d(n)\;(d(n)\in O(a(n)) \implies d(n)\in O(b(n)))$$
according to $(2)$ this means $O(a(n))\subseteq O(b(n))$.

A well known theorem about sets is the *transitivity* of the $\subseteq$ relation:

- *if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ then $A\subseteq C$*

It can be proven by using $(2)$ and I will leave this to you.

If $a\in O(b)$ and $b\in O(c)$, then $O(a)\subseteq O(b)$ and $O(b) \subseteq O(C)$. From the transitivity of the $\subseteq$ relation follows $O(a)\subseteq O(C))$ and so $a\in O(c)$.

From this we can conclude $g(n)\in O(f(n))$

---

We know $g \in O(f)$, so there is a $C$ and an $n_0$ such that

$$g(n)\le C_qf(n),\; \forall n\ge n_q$$
and so
$$g(n)\le C_qf(n),\; \forall n\ge n_q \text{ and } p \text{ is prime }$$
but $t(n)=g(n)$ if $n$ is a prime, so
$$t(n)\le C_1 f(n),\; \forall n\ge n_1 \text{ and } p \text{ is prime }$$
of course we have
$$f(n)\le 1\cdot f(n),\; \forall n\ge 1 \text{ and } p \text{ is not prime }$$
But $t(n)=f(n)$ for all $n$ that are not prime, so
$$t(n)\le 1\cdot f(n),\; \forall n\ge 1 \text{ and } p \text{ is not prime }$$
So finally we have
$$t(n)\le C f(n),\; \forall n\ge n_0$$
where $C=\{\max C_1,1\}$ and $n_0=\max\{n_1,1\}$
This means $t\in O(f)$.

---

Finally we want to show taht
$$O(h) \neq O(t)$$

If to sets are not equal then either one set is the subset of the other none of the sets is a subset of the other. The latter case applies to our inequality. There is an element in $O(h)$ that is not in $O(t)$ and there is an element in $O(t)$ that is not in $O(h)$. Actually the following is true:

- $h\not\in O(t))$ and $t \not\in O(h))$

We prove by contradiction. Assume $h\in O(h)$, then

Comment: @miracl173 Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain how $3n^4 \geq 3n^6 \geq 3f(n)$?

Comment: I think it's just a mistake

Comment: can you please correct your answer, so I mark it as answered :)

Comment: @lalaland I  corrected it. Yesterday I added a short aection that shows why $h(n)\not\in O(g(n))$. Maybe you can check this, too, if you haven't aleady done.

Comment: my bad. Thanks, I will mark it as answered